# error while compiling: gtksourceview/gtksource.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gtk, vala, gtksourceview

I am trying to make autocompletion using Gtk.SourceView. I added --pkg gtksourceview-3.0 in the makefile. Now when I try to make, it gives fatal error: gtksourceview/gtksource.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you confirmed that the package is installed? `sudo apt-get install gtksourceview-3.0`

Comment: yes package is installed

Comment: Install the header files: `sudo apt-get install libgtksourceview-3.0-dev` (on Debian based systems)

Comment: it is already installed. when i try the above command it says, libgtksourceview-3.0-dev is already the newest version

Comment: Show your makefile, show your sources, without it is just blind guessing

Answer (score 0):

Valac (or better gcc) search (by default) header files in ***/usr/include*** and ***/usr/local/include/***. 
Maybe apt-get did not copy these files in ***/usr/include/***.

So:

1.Open gtksourceview-3.0 package (default path of vapi files is ***/usr/share/vala/vapi*** or ***/usr/share/vala-0.20/vapi***)

2.Checks [cheader_filename]: if  it is something like:

```
  [CCode (cprefix..., cheader_filename = "gtksourceview/gtksource.h")]
```

then valac tries to use  ***/usr/include/gtksourceview/gtksource.h*** or ***/usr/local/include/gtksourceview/gtksource.h***

3.Check if ***/usr/include/gtksourceview*** contains gtksource.h

4.If not, search your ***gtksource.h***: we suppose that  is in ***/usr/include***. Then create a symbolic link:

`# ln -sf /usr/include/gtksource.h /usr/include/gtksourceview/gtksource.h`

Answer (score 0):

--pkg is only for the vala pass, if you do a C pass you need to do pkg-config manually for gcc
So, basically you have to require gtksourceview in the configure.ac so that they go in the cflags
that did the trick :)

thanks to friendly people on #vala irc channel